# Do you know other wave equations?

Tags: sound-effects

I know that if we run these formulas on some software like MatLab, we can obtain the waveforms of some effects:

```
- Ping wave:

f(t) = sin(2*pi*t*f) * exp(-t*4)

f(t) = sin(2*pi*t*f) * exp(-t*4) * (1 - exp( -t*10 )) * 2

- Ding-Dong wave

f(t) = sin(2*pi*t*725) * exp(-t*5) * (1 - exp(-t*30)) + (step(t-5) - step(t-.3)) * sin(2*pi*(t-.3)*565) * 1.3 * exp(-(t-.3)*5) * (1 - exp(-(t-.3)*30))
```

Here `pi` is π; `step` is a function that returns: 0 for t < 0, 1 for t >= 0; `f` is the frequency in Hertz.

Does anyone knows other formulas like these? I'm not looking for filters, or whatelse; i'm interested in equations to reproduce sounds like those I posted. Also links to books, sites, etc are welcome.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Be careful with your terminology.  Wave equation is a loaded term, meaning something very precise to [electrical engineers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_wave_equation), and something completely different than what you're looking for to [mechanical and acoustic engineers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation).  Physicists as well.

Comment: @MBraedley: while it's true that you would not normally call such equations _wave equations_, you can't say it's wrong: all of these are equations that have some particular types of waves as a solution (if we take _wave_ to mean a bounded function function defined on all ℝⁿ). Wave equations would normally be differential equations rather than such trivially-solvable pointwise definitions, but that's just because the involved physics happens to be of the form of differential equations.

Comment: @MBraedly is there a more precise term to use in this context? We can always edit the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The area of synthesis that's closest to the formulas you posted is [additive synthesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_synthesis).  Before I get into some sounds, one useful way to break up the formulas is into a waveform and an envelope.  For example, in the following formula you posted, the waveform is the sin() part, and the envelope is the combination of exp() functions:

```
f(t) = sin(2*pi*t*f) * exp(-t*4) * (1 - exp( -t*10 )) * 2
```

In fact, it's helpful if you think in terms of standard components of an analog synth--[Waveforms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waveforms), [Envelopes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADSR_envelope#ADSR_envelope), and [LFOs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-frequency_oscillation).  An example of an LFO would be using a low frequency sinusoid as an envelope, as follows:

**Amplitude Modulation**

```
sin(2*pi*t*f) * sin(2*pi*t*.01*f) * exp(-t*4)
```

Or you could use the LFO to modulate the frequency instead:

**Frequency Modulation**

```
sin(2*pi*t * sin(2*pi*t*.003*f)) * exp(-t*4)
```

Then you can get into different waveform types.  For example, a [sawtooth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave) with three harmonics:

**Sawtooth Wave**

```
exp(-t*4) * (sin(2*pi*t*f) + 1/2 * sin(2*pi*t*f*2) + 1/3 * sin(2*pi*t*f*3))
```

To add more harmonics to the sawtooth, the amplitudes are equal the inverse of the frequency, so the next few terms would be:

```
1/4 * sin(2*pi*t*f * 4) + 1/5 * sin(2*pi*t*f * 5) + ... + 1/n * sin(2*pi*t*f * n)
```

The first few terms of a [square wave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_wave), on the other hand, are:

**Square Wave**

```
exp(-t*4) * (sin(2*pi*t*f) + 1/3 * sin(2*pi*t*f*3) + 1/5 * sin(2*pi*t*f*5))
```

The formula is the same as the sawtooth, except only odd frequencies are used (i.e. 1,3,5,7,9,11...).

Those formulas are derived using [Fourier Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series), and if you've had any calculus, I'd recommend [these Stanford lectures as an introduction](http://see.stanford.edu/see/lecturelist.aspx?coll=84d174c2-d74f-493d-92ae-c3f45c0ee091).

Just mixing and matching various envelopes and waveforms can yield a large number of sounds, but here are a few other things to try:

**Detuning**

```
 sin(2*pi*t*f) +  sin(2*pi*t*f*1.005) +  sin(2*pi*t*f*.995)
```

**Inharmonic Frequencies**

Just about any "random" combination of frequencies will yield some kind of metallic-type sound.

```
 exp(-t*4) * (sin(2*pi*t*f) + sin(2*pi*t*f*2.13232) + sin(2*pi*t*f*6.12342))
```

**Analog Kick Drum**

The trick with these is to modulate both the frequency and the amplitude with an exponential.

```
 exp(-t*4) * sin(2*pi*t*f * exp(-t*20))
```

**Reese Bass**

This is just two sawtooths at 55hz, detuned by 50 cents (i.e. a factor of 2^(50/1200) = 1.0293)

```
detune = 1.0293
sin(2*pi*t*f) + 1/2 * sin(2*pi*t*f*2) + 1/3 * sin(2*pi*t*f*3) + 
sin(2*pi*t*f*detune) + 1/2 * sin(2*pi*t*f*2*detune) + 1/3 * sin(2*pi*t*f*3*detune)
```

--

It's really much easier to do this type of thing (i.e. sound rendering) with full programs rather than individual formulas.  If you want to get deeper into it, take a look at my answer to a related question [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/192/what-does-one-need-to-know-in-order-to-build-a-software-synthesizer/196#196).  Everything I reference there can be used as theory for deriving your own formulas.

Comment: Great answer, full of references and examples! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

*Sound On Sound* magazine has [a series of articles on audio synthesis](http://www.soundonsound.com/search?PageSize=80&Keyword=%22synth%20secrets%22) freely available on their website, outlining the theory and math involved in a variety of traditional synthesis techniques.